# Angular production not working on website

Tags: javascript, angular

I have developed a simple Angular app that works perfectly in developing mode but produces an error when building with `ng build` or `ng build --prod`.

error:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Clicking on the error opens up a html page highlighting "<!DOCTYPE html>". The html page is from the root index.php file which the Angular shouldn't try to access.

Is the problem that Angular doesn't know it's position in the file system?

**Edit:**
It's been solved.
The problem was that the angular program was not in the root folder of the server.

A fix to this is ti manually change the index.html in the dist folder. There is a tag element called base that indicates where the base root folder for the angular app is, *<\base href="/home/">*. Change it to your prefered subfolder for your angular app.

Comment: What is your Angular version?

Comment: It's Angular CLI 6.0.8

Comment: CLI is the Command Line Interface, not the framework. But I guess you are not using AngularJS, but Angular. Gonna edit the post.

Comment: you're right sorry I'm still very new to angular, I didn't think there was any difference

Comment: No problem, AngularJS is Angular 1.x and is very very different from Angular on which you are working. I hope you'll get best luck with accurate tagging ;)

Comment: what are you using to run the built app? you'll need to use a http server, it will not work to simply open the index.html in your browser

Comment: This is possibly problem with bundle, did you use aot?

Comment: I put the content from "dist/TEST" into a folder named "TEST" on my server. It's hosted and run with apache

Comment: @Drag13 I have not tried aot. I'm gonna give it a shot.

Comment: I still get the same error with aot. Angular website says this about ng build: "This command will compile a production ready version of your application in the dist/ folder". Which made me think I just have to put the folder to my server. I'm probably misunderstanding, Is there something more I need to add?

Comment: @Elias Not familiar with apache but shouldn't it be index.html or smth like that on the server root?

Comment: Okay now it works, but I was also a bit afraid I would need to put it into the root folder as I already have a page there. Is there some way I can move the angular app to a subfolder?